# Intentional deviation from direction of Qibla

Tags: qiblah

Assalamo alaikum wrwb,

I am in Toronto. We have started a new Mussallah here. We are facing towards the main wall keeping the rows parallel to front wall, while the Qibla is about 15-20 degrees towards right side. The managements says that this way they can save the space and can accommodate more people during Ramadan or Jummah etc. Is it ok to tilt the direction approx 15-20 degrees based on just these reasons?

Comment: Increase the number of jamaa's going on

Comment: I wouldn't prefer to do so intentionally.

Answer (score 2):

The European Council for Fatwa and Research rejected such practice and mentioned that continuing to do so intentionally while knowing the ruling would void prayers.

Source: https://www.e-cfr.org/fatwa/%D9%82%D8%A8%D9%84-%D8%A8%D8%B6%D8%B9-%D8%B3%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D8%A3%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%A9-%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%A5%D9%82-3/